# can't push or pull to a docker repo `Repository not found`

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am new to docker. created a public repo under my account 
[link to repo](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/opmaster/basic_server/)

I am able to pull other public repos like redis and debian:

```
docker ps                                    ✱
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
40416ad4c715        debian:latest       "/bin/sh -c 'while t   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                            dal_server
```

but when trying to pull from my repo i get an error:

```
docker pull opmaster/basic_server            ✱
Pulling repository opmaster/basic_server
FATA[0009] Repository not found

docker push opmaster/basic_server            ✱
The push refers to a repository [opmaster/basic_server] (len: 0)
FATA[0000] Repository does not exist: opmaster/basic_server
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>> docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE

debian              latest              41b730702607        10 days ago         125.1 MB
hello-world         latest              91c95931e552        3 weeks ago         910 B

>> docker tag 41b730702607 opmaster/basic_server:devel
>> docker push opmaster/basic_server
```

> docker push can get be  little long from my short experience, so i stopped it with `ctrl-c`, did  `boot2docker restart` and started again with the `docker push opmaster/basic_server`

if someone knows a better way, i'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have a valid image on dockerhub.  How did you create the image that is there?  I see if, but there isn't anything in it.

Your images are created by pushing an image that you have locally, or with a Dockerfile (you can buuild an image).  There is a good write up on how to push an image here:

```
https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerrepos/
```

Once you get a valid image pushed, pulling it will be possible.  I have found pushing images (like the one you have listed in your docker ps) is easier to do if you tag it first.  However, the easiest way to make images is to create a project for it on github, have a Dockerfile in that project, then auto build it (github checkin triggers a build on dockerhub).

Comment: i tried to push a the debian using `docker push opmaster/basic_server ` but i get an error which i listed there . maybe my syntax is off.

Comment: what are you trying to push?  the web page i referenced above shows how to push an image.  it references the url: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/ , if you scroll down there you will see 'Creating our own images'.  In those directions you will see how to commit your image, and then tag it. Once that is done you can push it.